# How to combine wall outlets for higher amperage?

Tags: ac, mains, fuses, load, ac-motor

I have a large single phase AC motor that draws 30 amps at 125v. I only have access to NEMA 5-15R outlets (which are rated for 15 amps). However, several outlets are on different lines (different fuses) i.e. I can draw 15 amps from multiple outlets at the same time.

Is there a way to spread the load of this motor across 2 (or more) outlets so that each outlet supplies less than 15 amps while the motor receives all 30 amps it needs?

Comment: Home Improvement is a better place for this question.  A number of electricians hang out there.

Comment: Also consider, what's that motor's starting current?

Comment: Also, what you are describing is the basis of a 3 phase motor, commonly used is large industrial plants. But you need to receive a special hook up from the power company to do that (and get all 3 phases). As others have pointed out below, if you try this on a home electrical system - you only have 1 phase (and the negative of it as the "other" phase) - combining these into one mega circuit is very dangerous to you and power company workers for many many reasons.

Comment: On kitchen you may have split receptacles. It two different phase on double breaker, 240V/15A. Replace it with receptacle 240V/15A. Use transformer 240/120V, 3.6kW.

Comment: You CAN. But nobody will tell you that you SHOULD. There is no safe or standard way to do it. That is the problem.

Comment: What you can do is call an electrician and ask them to install a 30A, 120V AC outlet. These exist. I think the most common one would be NEMA L5-30. You could install it yourself but you have to use 10 AWG wire. If your existing outlets used 10AWG wire you could just take out the regular outlet and install the 30 Amp outlet. Then change the breaker for that outlet to 30A instead of 20.

Comment: Seeing as how it's already been answered, I will decline to move it, there are a few motor people on here.

Answer (score 17):

No.

1. The circuits may be on different phases or on opposing split phase.
2. If one plug is removed from its socket its pins will be live due to backfeed from the other circuit. This presents an electrocution hazard.
3. You'll have two parallel circuit breakers if they are on the same phase.

Don't mess around with this. Install the proper circuit.

Comment: Not just "no" but NO! ABSOLUTELY NOT!  Doing this is incredibly dangerous.

Comment: Yep. Found #1 the hard way during kitchen renovation - installed new wall sockets without removing break-off bridges first.

Comment: @Maple Is that to code? Two separate phases to a single outlet? I know that in kitchens they'll run separate phases to adjacent outlets, but haven't heard of this in a single outlet.

Comment: @Maple just checked with electrician that I know. He said, it's not common, but yep, it is legal.  Learned something new!

Comment: @Aaron It is common. Just has to be double breaker, then one circuit overcurrent, both disconnected.

Comment: Two opposite-phase hots to a split duplex outlet was not only common, but required, on Canadian kitchen counters. (but that is not relevant to the OP's question)

Answer (score 3):

Quick and safe answer: you don't. Ever. Even assuming an european system and not the american split-phase system, the distribution impedence doesn't ensure that your load
will be split correctly between the outlets so you'll probably overload one. Depending on your regulation it could be even explicitly forbidden (in EU it is, at least for machinery)

The right solution is either a bigger outlet on a bigger feed line (I don't know the NEMA sizings, sorry) or use a feeder more suitable for your load, like a full 240V line in US or even better a 3-phase feed.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's insane that you have a \$30\:\text{A}\: @\: 120\:\text{V}\$ motor. It's not even common for these to be \$240\:\text{V}\$ in order to reduce the current. At that power, nearly 5 horsepower, these motors are almost always 3-phase where it just makes so much sense. A 3-phase motor always starts in the right direction without shading or start capacitors and it's lots more efficient, as well.

So I'm actually kind of shocked that such a thing exists, at all. I mean, I believe people could do it. But why? If you are in a position to want to power such a beast, you'd probably already have access to 3-phase (or should.)

But given that you have one and need a \$30\:\text{A}\$ circuit, you should do what's right and arrange on your entrance panel a proper breaker for \$30\:\text{A}\$ and run appropriate wiring over to your motor. Given the inductance involved it's almost certain you should have an appropriate amount of "run" capacitance, as well. (I'm guessing, but I suspect your motor will have both a "start" and also a "run" capacitor. Make sure these are well-functioning and sized appropriately. It's important if this is a single-phase motor.)

And no, it's not safe to consider "tapping into" two outlets. You already know this I gather, but outlets rated at \$15\:\text{A}\$ on the same circuit cannot be aggregated. All of them together must be limited to the same \$15\:\text{A}\$ maximum. So given that outlets are on different breakers, this only means that they may... or may not... be on the same phase of the split-phase system. If they are on opposite phases, you are definitely screwed. Hooking up L1 to L2 is not going to be a matter of joy, but instead great horror. If you are lucky enough that they are both on the same half of the split-phase system, it's possible that some later change to your entrance panel will move a breaker from the same half to a different half at a later time, with disastrous results! So while it may work for a time, you leave open a booby trap for someone later to encounter unexpected horror. Do not set up this trap! Also, you'd want both entrance panel breakers to be joined so that if one flips they both flip together. And that's not generally easy to arrange on most panels I've seen. This whole idea is bad.

The upshot here is that you need to do this right. Get the right gauge for the length involved, get the right breaker, and get the right plug, as well (5-30R, probably.) Also, obey modern requirements. These include using armor-clad wiring if your breakers aren't dual-ACFI and GFCI protected (unless under 2" or more of concrete.) There are a lot of details about making this right. So read up or get informed advice about it from your local county officials. (They can help you and will try, if you allow them the chance.)

Comment: Another thing. Neutrals are not protected, they depend on only carrying current from the corresponding hot. If you parallel two hots and two neutrals and one of the neutrals fails (open or high resistance), the remaining neutral will carry the full 30 amps and burn up!

Comment: @DoxyLover Yeah. I didn't want to think through all the details of attempting to wire up two breakers in parallel. It's just NOT a good idea, so "full stop NO." But yes, that's another problem among several with the idea. One of the hots could also fail open, too. Too many bad possibilities to try and list. (I can think of more -- dual ACFI events on either hot but not the other and GFCI too, for example, as well as wanting both entrance panel breakers to fail together if anything happens. My mind boggles.)

Comment: I don't think 30A would be 5 HP. Somewhere over 3 HP, though. There are lots of single phase 240V 3 HP motors available. Heavier duty power tools use them. 3 phase is not always available, so there is definitely a market for 3 HP 240V single phase motors.

Comment: @mkeith I guess my own experiences are limited. To get my HP figure I just multiplied out to get the input power using rms. I would guess the delivered mechanical power would be less, granted.

Comment: Yeah you have to apply power factor and also efficiency. Just as a guess maybe both are 80 percent. So output power = rated voltage * rated current * 0.64 might be realistic. So that would be just a little over 3 HP. I bet it is a 3 HP motor. I think maybe I saw a 3 HP motor that could be wired for 120V once. Does not seem very common.

Answer (score 0):

How much money are you willing to spend on this?  I can think of a number of solutions, all of which can cost a lot of money.

One solution is to spread the power needed over time, assuming the motor is not running continuously at full output.  Get a large battery, a 15 amp 125 volt battery charger, and a 30 amp 125 volt inverter.  Hook the battery up to the charger and inverter.  Plug the charger into the wall, the motor into the inverter.  Keep the duty cycle on the motor under 50%, and any continuous run within the capacity of the battery, and you'll be fine.

One thing to keep in mind is that the motor isn't going to take 30 amps unless under maximum load.  It might average under 15 amps even with the losses from the battery and electronics.

Another idea would be a setup with motors and generators.  Give me enough time and a better idea on what you are trying to accomplish and I could come up with more ideas.  The problem will be that I expect none of my ideas to be of lower cost than hiring an electrician to run a proper circuit for your motor.